# C++ How to define an operator that is inside a nested class

Tags: c++, class, nested, operator-overloading

I am having trouble with defining an operator that is within a nested class that is also templated. I understand how to declare and define it within the .h file, but I want to declare it in the .h file and define it in a .hpp file. For example:

List.h

```
template <typename T>
class List {
public:
    class const_iterator {   //nested class
        //....
        const T & operator*() const;
    };
};
```

Now here is the part I don't quite understand:

List.hpp

```
#include "List.h"
template <typename T>
typename List <T>::const_iterator & List <T>:: operator*() const //error line
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The error I am receiving on line 4 of the Line.hpp is:

> Out-of-line definition of 'operator*' does not match any declaration in 'List<T>'

I am looking for a solution that involves solely fixing the .hpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, your definition doesn't match your declaration.  You've declared a member `operator*` of the class `List<T>::const_iterator` that returns a `const T&`, but your definition is for the member `operator*` of the class `List<T>` that returns a `List<T>::const_iterator&`.

Definitions of member functions of class templates, nested or not, follow the same pattern as any other function: `ReturnType FunctionName(ParameterList)`

The appropriate definition for that declaration is:

```
  template <typename T>
  const T& List<T>::const_iterator::operator*( ) const
//^^^^^^^^                                    ^
// |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ |
// Return type        |                       (empty) parameter list
//                    Function name
  {
      //...
  }
```

Comment: now what if i had something like: const_iterator & operator++(); within the .h file?

Answer (score 2):

Your .hpp is trying to define an `operator*` that is a member of `List<T>` and returns a reference to a `List<T>::const_iterator`. That is not what your .h declares. It declares an `operator*` that is a member of `List<T>::const_iterator` and returns a reference to a `T`.

Try this instead:

```
#include "List.h"

template <typename T>
const T& List<T>::const_iterator::operator*() const
{
    //do stuff
}
```